# MediaSessionCompat not showing a RemoteControlClient on API < Lollipop

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-support-library

I'm using MediaSessionCompat in an app using support 22.2.0, and it's working great on Lollipop, but it's not creating the RemoteControlClient for lock screen controls in version less than Lollipop (Testing with a KitKat device).

```
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 99, new Intent(ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTONS), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MediaControlReceiver.class.getName());
    mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, "PlayerService", receiver, pi);
    mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCallbacks());
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    controller = mediaSession.getController();
```

I have a BroadcastReceiver set up in my Manifest to listen to the MEDIA_BUTTON action that I'm feeding into the PendingIntent and everything seems to looks like it's set up, so I'm not sure why it isn't displaying a RemoteControl on the Lockscreen below KitKat. What am I missing?

```
   <receiver android:name=".ui.audiobook.player.RemoteControlReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.app.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: 1. What does the ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTONS constant point to? The Intent should be new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON)

Comment: 2. Also the intent-filter needs to point to `android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I was forgetting to set the PlayState in the MediaSession, which makes the RemoteControlClient show up on devices not running Lollipop.